# How do I raise and then catch and flash this error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in user_documents_controller.rb you're saying

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_document

  def download
    file = @document.external_document
    if file.nil?
      render 'the_view_you_called_this_action', flash[:error]: 'Document not found' # Or probably you need to use flash.now[:error] = 'Document not found'
      return
    end
    # The rest of your code
  end
end
```

but I got this error `ActionController::UnknownFormat at /documents/ee3ej2e2oijwejdowj/download UserDocumentsController#download is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant:`

but if I do it like this:

```
# Downloads a document from the Java-Backend and sends it to the client
  def download
   if file = @document.external_document
     original_filename = file.headers['content-disposition'].partition('filename=').last
     original_filetype = File.extname(original_filename)

     send_data file, filename: "#{@document.meta.title}#{original_filetype}", type: file.headers['content-type']
  else
    if file.nil?
      redirect_to user_document_path, flash.now[:error] = 'Document not found'
      end
   end
   end
```

I get this error: `undefined method 'partition' for nil:NilClass` in line `original_filename = file.headers['content-disposition'].partition('filename=').last` when the document doesn't exist, if it does then I can download the doc.

Comment: In your controller, when are you calling the `orginal_document` method from your `pds_backend.rb`? And, in that method, where and when do you want to raise the error?

Comment: @gasc I want to raise the error when the user clicks on download button and the file is missing to give him a flash error ("dialog box").

Comment: What does the method `external_document` do?

Comment: Returns external document hash from Java-Backend

Answer (score 1):

Doing *a lot* of assumptions about your code, you can do something like this:

```
# In your controller
class YourController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_document

  def download
    file = @document.external_document
    if file.nil?
      render 'the_view_you_called_this_action', flash[:error]: 'Document not found' # Or probably you need to use flash.now[:error] = 'Document not found'
      return
    end
    # The rest of your code
  end
end
```

Comment: I applied your solution, but now I get this error: undefined method `headers' for nil:NilClass in this line original_filename = file.headers['content-disposition'].partition('filename=').last

Comment: Again, we need more information to help you. When does the method `orginal_document` from your `PdsBackend`gets called? When and how does the instance variable `@document` gets initialized?? Can you update your question and add more of your code?

Comment: I see now original_document is not called in user_documents_controller and the `@document`is here: 
`# Sets a single user document by the *id* parameter
  #
  # @return [UserDocument] found user document
  def set_document
    @document ||= UserDocument.find(params[:id])
  end`

Comment: I updated my answer. Maybe something like that helps, but you really need to put more of your code, I'm assuming most of your code, it's hard to help you without more information. If my answer doesn't work, please update your *orignal* question with all the code relevant to it

Comment: Now I get:

message:
  Calling Document.find with nil is invalid.
summary:
  Document.find expects the parameters to be 1 or more ids, and will return a single document if 1 id is provided, otherwise an array of documents if multiple ids are provided.
resolution:
  Most likely this is caused by passing parameters directly through to the find, and the parameter either is not present or the key from which it is accessed is incorrect.

p.s. I will update my question now.

Comment: I edited my question, notice I want the error to be displayed as a flash message (dialog box) not redirect the user to another page.

Comment: One observation, forget about the `DocumentNotDownloadedError` thing, that whats just a suggestion before knowing your code, you don't needed it.

I think that with a simple check for `file.nil?` in the second line of your controller you're good. I've updated my answer

Comment: I still have an error, looks like it is from the view: ActionController::UnknownFormat at /documents/ee3ej2e2oijwejdowj/download
UserDocumentsController#download is missing a template for this request format and variant.

request.formats: ["text/html"]
request.variant: []

Comment: I tried putting  `redirect_to user_document_path` instead of `render` but still the same error

Comment: I updated my question again with your answer and the error.